# Ruby reopening classes -- can overridden methods be accessed?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know if I subclass the String class and override its capitalize method, I can call the String class' version of capitalize with `super`.  What if instead I reopened the String class and rewrote the capitalize method?  Is there a way I can call the previous version of that method?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4470108/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not out of the box.  A common approach is to rename the existing method to a new name.  Then, in your rewritten version, call the old method by the new name.

```
def String
    alias to_i old_to_i
    def to_i
       #add your own functionality here
       old_to_i
    end
end
```

You might also want to look at `alias_method_chain`, which does some of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another interesting approach to get `super` working - if the class to open supports it (e.g. because it's written by yourself):

The methods of the class are not directly defined in the class body, but in another module that is then included. To overwrite a method of the re-opened class, include your own module with the extend version of it (which might use `super`).

This is, for example, used in the irb-alternative [ripl](https://github.com/cldwalker/ripl) to let plugins implement their own versions of core methods (which call `super` to get the original behaviour).